# CloudRun returns 0 bytes response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We migrated our app (Java, SpringBoot) from Heroku to GCP Cloud Run, after facing some performance-related issues I modified our REST endpoint to use a non-blocking way of serving requests and encountered a weird problem.

When the non-blocking change was deployed to the CloudRun all related endpoints return 0 bytes response (reported by any browser or cURL), even though CloudRun logs report proper response size:

> responseSize: "1137"

Things I've tried so far without success:

- to exclude LoadBalancer out of the equation I enabled public access and tried to hit CloudRun directly
- to make sure it is not related to Tomcat I replaced it with Jetty
- I tried both generations of CloudRun instances

It works fine locally or from a docker container but returns 0 bytes responses on the CloudRun.

What could be the reason? What can I check on my side while waiting for the support to deal with the issue?

UPDATE:
Result of calling `cURL -L -i -v`:

> - Trying 34.36.35.1:443...
> - Connected to ***** (34.36.35.1) port 443 (#0)
> - ALPN, offering h2
> - ALPN, offering http/1.1
> - successfully set certificate verify locations:
> - CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
> - CApath: none
> - (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
> - (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
> - (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
> - (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
> - (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
> - (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
> - SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
> - ALPN, server accepted to use h2
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: CN=***********
> - start date: Jun 15 15:58:36 2023 GMT
> - expire date: Sep 13 16:52:50 2023 GMT
> - subjectAltName: host "*************" matched cert's "*************"
> - issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1D4
> - SSL certificate verify ok.
> - Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
> - Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
> - Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
> - Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x12c00e000)
> - GET /api/user/permissions HTTP/2
> - Host: *************
> - user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0
> - some irrelevant headers, like user agent, etc. *
> - < HTTP/2 200 HTTP/2 200 < vary: Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Accept-Encoding,
> - User-Agent vary:
> - Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Accept-Encoding,
> - User-Agent < cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform,
> - no-store cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-transform,
> - no-store < x-content-type-options: nosniff x-content-type-options:
> - nosniff < x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block < referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin
> - referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin
> - content-type: application/json content-type: application/json
> - x-cloud-trace-context: 1dfe301ceac344ebb4b30eed4c89a495;o=1
> - x-cloud-trace-context: 1dfe301ceac344ebb4b30eed4c89a495;o=1
> - < date: Wed, 05 Jul 2023 16:02:11 GMT date: Wed, 05 Jul 2023 16:02:11 GMT
> - server: Google Frontend server: Google Frontend
> - content-length: 0
> - content-length: 0 < via: 1.1 google via: 1.1 google <
> - strict-transport-security: 31536000 strict-transport-security:
>   31536000 < alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
>   alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
> - Connection #0 to host ************ left intact

Comment: What do the Cloud Run logs show? Post the relevant entries. Use the CLI `curl` command with debug enabled. Show the entire cmd, request, and response (redacted). Example `curl -L -i -v URL`.

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with the curl request `GET /api/user/permissions`. Status is 200 and Content-Length is 0. Post the relevant Cloud Run logs for the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem and post an answer for anyone facing a similar issue.
It turned out that the problem was unrelated to the CloudRun, the responseSize reported by CloudRun logs misled me, in reality, the responseBody was 0 bytes and the size reported by CR apparently was the size of headers.

To root cause of the problem was a filter forcibly flushing the response right after delegating the processing to another thread, before the future was completed. It was configured to run only in production - that's why I was not able to reproduce it locally.